# Extension mysqli is missing, phpmyadmin doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem with phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04.
I have already installed apache2, php5, mysql and phpmyadmin.

The `phpinfo();` script, don't show nothing about mysqli or mysql extension.

When I try start phpmyadmin this error appear:

```
----
**phpMyAdmin - Error**
-------
**The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.**
----
```

In the php.ini file, I uncommented `extension=mysql.so` line, but doesn't work...

Anyone have another posible solution?

Comment: Did you restart apache after uncommenting the line?

Comment: I feel some dumb after this.. :P
Thanks Henry, i powered on my computer today and all work, thank you!

Comment: Restart the apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: please close this issue if you get your answer

Comment: @HardikGajjar how can you close a question? Welcome to SO.

Comment: @Timo my bad, I was rookie that time, It's too old comment

Comment: @HardikGajjar Probably the most antique claim I ever read. This remains open indeed.

Comment: Actually that time i was about to convey mark the answer.Lollz

Comment: @HardikGajjar Yeah, but it is closed now! And it only takes me 9 years to choose the best answer.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Latest phpMyAdmin versions require mysqli extension and will no longer work with mysql one (note the extra "i" at the end of its name).

**For PHP 7.3**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysqli
```

**For PHP 8**

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysqli
```

Will install package containing both old one and the new one, so afterwards all you need to do is to add

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

in your php.ini, under the subject Dynamic Extensions.

Restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Authenticate if needed and press enter.

Should be done! If problem still occurs remove the browser cache.

Comment: If the problem still re-occurs after this, clear your browser cache

Comment: Works for php7.4 as well, just use: sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysqli

Comment: What do you mean by authenticating in `Authenitacate and press enter`? The restart of apache2?

Comment: Guys, php8 is out since more than a year and there is not one entry mentioning php8. Welcome to SO. Package is `php8.0-mysql`.

Comment: @Timo Authenticate and press Enter, is for entering your password when Sudo prompts you to do it. And comment that the package version is outdated, in an answer from almost nine years,... just edit it.

Comment: you can try `sudo apt-get install php-mysqli`, if  `sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysqli` not work.

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

try both of alternatively it works for me

Comment: My apt-get cannot find these packages. Does anyone know what repositories they are in?

Comment: actually php5 version deprecated from repo . please try this PPA from link http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @HardikGajjar That question is about downgrading to php5.  Why not just install the php7.0 version? `$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: @NealGokli In my case I have to php5, because I can't install php7.0-gd on Debian Jessie. It requires a too high version of **libwebp5** that is not available through the apt. It used to work but since about half a year it's broken.

Comment: Can anyone explain Why this issue happens ? 
In my localhost it happens so many times.

Comment: @KetavChotaliya According to my knowledge there is installation problem in your system you need to check which component needs to be installed.

Answer (score 31):

If you run PHPMyAdmin on localhost uncomment in file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` this line:

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This solution is used when the MySQLi extension is properly installed, but phpMyAdmin is running on localhost.

Comment: Works on PHP 7 as well (just note that the new php.ini location is `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`).

Answer (score 7):

Just restart the apache2 and mysql:

- **apache2:** `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
- **mysql:** `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

then refresh your browser, enjoy phpmyadmin :)

Comment: It is really as trivial as that.
The extension gets installed with phpmyadmin and needs a restart (apache, php5-fpm whatever).

Many 'solutions' here do have the reload of the webserver as final step and in fact - in my opinion this is the only thing needed.

Comment: It really isn't as trivial as that. :-)  You need to install the mysql/mysqli extension.

Comment: Far away in time, I asked this, never closed the topic. In fact, the first comment answered my question, but it's a comment, so I will take this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a lot of the answers and none of them seemed to work because php7.0 is not the default.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

seemed to do the job for me but I had to reinstall php7.0 and phpmyadmin after that:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though you are small your answer is big. Helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I faced same issue and **resolved** it by doing following steps:

1. First check PHP versions. If you have multiple PHP Versions. Suppose you have PHP versions like php7.0, php7.1 and php 7.2 then
2. run these commands

**For PHP7.0**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqlnd
```

**For PHP7.1**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysqlnd
```

**For PHP7.2**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqlnd
```

**For PHP7.3**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysqlnd
```

3. Edit the ini file and look for mysqli. Uncomment the line by removing **;**
   for all php versions

   extension=mysqli.so

> `/etc/php/<php.version>/apache2/php.ini`

**For PHP7.0**

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

**For PHP7.1**

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
```

**For PHP7.2**

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

**For PHP7.3**

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
```

and last restart apache server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 2021. None of these packages is available anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by editing /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini.

(found it by doing netstat -nlp ¦ grep apache, then strace -p somepid ¦ grep php.ini).

At the end of the file, I added:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so
```

Adding it without the path did not work.

Then after a restart it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu user open your terminal and type following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

After that just restart apache2 by typing this

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

refresh you browser and enjoy phhmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 users with php-fpm
I fixed the issue by adding the full path in the php conf:

> edit /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini

and replace

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

with:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so
```

Comment: This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop with **PHP 7.4**, **PHP 8.0.7**, **MySQL 8.0.25** setup. What I did was edited `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` and replaced e lines as you said in both the files. Later restarted both, PHP and MySQL by `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and `sudo systemctl restart mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the extension_dir is one of the thing you like to check from phpinfo().In my case it was extension_dir = "./" by default which was wrong. Change it to extension_dir = './ext/' or where all your extension dlls are currently residing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your php.ini if you are using XAMPP etc. also check if it is already there just remove ; from front of it

```
extension= php_mysqli.dll
```

and stop and start apache and MySQL it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need the MySQLi module. This error usually occurs when manually installing phpMyAdmin.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql
```

It will return you with.

```
[Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini with new version]

[Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version]
```

Then.

```
sudo service apache2 restart.
```

Then.

```
Press F5 on your browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me , make a database with a php and mysql script and open up the mysql console and type in create user 'yourName'@'127.0.0.1' and then type in grant all privileges on *.* to 'yourName'@'127.0.0.1' then open up a browser go to localhost and a database should been made and then go to your phpmyadmin page and you will see it pop up there.

Answer (score 0):

at ubuntu 12.04 i had to change `mssql.compatability_mode = On`.
put On and works

Comment: Where do you change this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I had this problem following an upgrade, I just disable Apache2-php5

```
a2dismod php5
```

and activated php7

```
a2enmod php7
```

Hope it may help anybody!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error on ubuntu and what worked for me was editing 2 lines in /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

```
  ;extension=mysqli to   extension=mysqli
```

and gave the **extension** variable location to **mysqli.so** after uncommenting it

```
   extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so
```

then restart the service just to make sure

```
systemctl start mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, my system is Ubuntu Server 20.04 and none of the solutions here worked. For me, I installed PHP 7.4 and I had to edit `enter code here`/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`.

Within this, search for `;extension=mysqli`, uncomment and change `mysqli` to `mysqlnd` so it should look like this `extension=mysqlnd`. I tried using `mysqli` but I faced the same error as if I didn't enable it but `mysqlnd` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the very same problem, but in my case the reason was update of Ubuntu and php version - from 18.04 and php-7.2 up to 20.04 and php-7.4.

The Nginx server was the same, so in my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** was old data:

```
server {
  location /pma {
    location ~ ^/pma/(.+\.php)$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
  }
}
```

I could not get phpmyadmin to work with any of php.ini changes and all answers from this thread, but at some moment I had opened the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and realised, that I still had old version of php. So I just changed it to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

and the issue was gone, phpmyadmin magically started to work without any mysqli-file complaint. I even double checked it, but yeap, that's how it works - if you have wrong version for php-fpm.sock in your nginx config file, your phpmyadmin will not work, but the shown reason will be **'The mysqli extension is missing'**

Answer (score 0):

I hope my successful answer helps someone in recent times as I had to try many mix-and-matches and then found it:

This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop with **PHP v7.4**, **PHP v8.0.7** and **MySQL v8.0.25** setup.

What I did was edited `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` files and replaced
`extension=mysqli.so`
with
`extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so`
in both the files.

Later, restarted both of these (PHP and MySQL) by `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and `sudo systemctl restart mysql`. Refreshed Chrome, and phpMyAdmin responded with the login screen.

(**UPDATE:** Please check if you have `/usr/lib/php/20200930/mysqli.so` file as well. I tested this as it looked newer by directory date, and this too worked in both the PHP files as `extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/mysqli.so`)