# Issue with PHP MySQL on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm new to PHP, MySQL dev. I'm trying to make a simple webapp, was following a tutorial. 
This is the PHP script it showed to grab info about the 'detectives' table.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root!', 'intrepid_detectives');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM detectives");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

But when I open this page on my browser by going to `localhost/index.php`, it gives me this error:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://localhost/index.php`. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

I asked a guy, he said the problem is with `mysqli`, so I searched on SO, and followed  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work), but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try :

- can you open a simple html file in the same directory, index.html for example ?
- did you try showing the errors on page with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ? Or is there something in the error.log ?
- do you have a .htaccess or vhost configuration that could interfere with what you want?

Checking these will certainly point you to the right direction I hope :)

Comment: Yep, I have other HTML pages in that directory which works fine. And I tried running some simple PHP scripts (echo "Hello World") which also work fine.

Comment: I tried following this question again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work  And it works now. Thanks a lot for your help! :D