# phpMyAdmin on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin utilizing the PHP SDK kit. I am getting this phpMyAdmin error in my local test environment:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

Anyone have any recommendations for the app.yaml file that would work best with phpMyAdmin and google app engine utilizing PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work

Comment: Locally, or when you deploy?

Comment: I am running it locally in a test environment.

Comment: I was able to fix the missing extension by placing a copy of my php.ini file in the root directory of my application. I also added the following to the php.ini file google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name,gc_enabled"

Ok, now I am not getting errors however I may have some issues with my yaml file since my images are not loading and I get this message "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated."

Comment: You might like this article: [phpMyAdmin on Google App Engine](http://novelcode.blogspot.in/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html).

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me -

```
application: phpmyadmin
version: pn
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: phpmyadmin/\1

- url: /(.+\.php)\?.+$
  script: phpmyadmin/\1

- url: /
  script: phpmyadmin/index.php

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: phpmyadmin/\1
  upload: phpmyadmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true
```