# can't establish php connection to mysql db even though mysql server is running

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

First time user of mysql and php here.

Apache2 is up and running. PHP5 is up and running. MYSQL is up and running; however, when I try to connect to my database I created, i receive a "server error" message with Chromium. With Firefox, there is just a blank page that displays, no error message. The code I've written should spout out an error on the page, but I'm getting a browser "Server error" message instead.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db1');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
  echo 'failed to connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

I'm very confused, because i checked to make sure the mysql server was running, and I double checked my login information as well as database name. I can make changes and create databases from the mysql shell within terminal, but not through PHP!

I'd also add that PHP is working with the Apache server. If i change my code to something like phpinfo(), it works. It's only connecting to mysql that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Check your server/php error logs, could be a syntax error, could be invalid creds, maybe you don't have mysqli installed, etc.

Comment: And BTW, the blank page is almost always PHP throwing a fatal error.

Comment: I installed the php5-mysql package through apt-get as well as mysqlserver, is there anything else i should need?

Comment: Look, you haven't even setup your dev environment. You should not be writing code yet. First things first: http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Comment: thanks guys...it's up and running now. turning the errors on didn't actually help (but it will in the future while I'm coding!), all I had to do was restart apache...I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In past, before using wamp for my php work, I fell in this issue once, and believe me, it was **mysqli** extension which wasnt installed..to solve this issue,

turn your errors **ON** , so that you can see exactly whats going on...see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)
check your **php.ini** and make sure that **#** signed is not present before **mysqli** extension...see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work)

I am quite sure that these two steps will resolve your issue