# Connect PHP with MySQL on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 and also installed MySQL and PHP. When running separately, both PP and MySQL are working fine. However when I try to connect MySQL with PHP, it does not show any errors nor will it connect. Separately PHP and MySQL are working fine. I also run this command:

```sh
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

It shows every thing updated and that I  have installed PHP and MySQL.

I used:

```php
mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root') or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db('databasename') or die(mysqli_error());
$resources = mysqli_query('select * from users');
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_object($resources)) {
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($data);
}
```

but the pages show a white screen.

Comment: Honest question: why not use something already established, like XAMPP?

Comment: check your error_log (/var/log/apache2/error.log).

Comment: Well, you should get an error. Either the login credentials are wrong, or it should trigger an error when you try to run a query without a database selected (which you can't do if you're not logged into the server)...

Comment: @Mave Seriously? XAMPP on a LAMP-Stack? Are you kidding?

Comment: @BenM it has to be a Fatal error, if the credentials are wrong, the script would die and output the error

Comment: @Flask, what has to be a fatal error?

Comment: @BenM the error which occurs. either the table is empty and there is no error, or PHP throws a fatal which gets suppressed by config. (e.g. mysqli_connect isn't available).

Comment: Sounds like php is set to not display errors. You could turn them on in your php.ini `display_errors on` or in command line `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` then watch it as you run your script in browser. This should show your error

Comment: No there is no any error even no any notice . Mave xamp on lamp :)

Comment: It was an honest question - I don't know anything about Ubuntu. I've literally started using it 90 minutes ago.

Comment: You install `php5-mysql` but then try to use mysqli.

Comment: related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work

Comment: @Mave - It's the first time I hear that the official binaries of one of the leading Linux distros (specially crafted to fit into the system and receive automatic security updates) are not "established enough". What are the benefits of installing a third-party package? The fun of trying to make things work manually?

Comment: have you restarted your webserver after installing php5-mysql?

Comment: Ok thats cool but in when i tries mysql instead of mysqli then is shows the same white screen

Comment: Yes i have restarted my webserver and restart my pc too

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Never mentioned _anything_ about not being established enough?

Comment: @Mave - "why not use something already established" suggests so, doesn't it? In any case, the usual problem with official binaries is that they're normally very outdated (save for security patches). But they're fairly good for most situations since they "just work".

Comment: Thanx all for suggestion now able to connect mysqli with php. It was silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are a couple of hints:

- A blank page (or a "500 Internal Server Error" status code) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code properly without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).
- You've apparently installed the deprecated legacy mysql extension ([Original MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)):

  ```
  apt-get install php5-mysql
  ```

  ... but you're actually using the modern mysqli extension ([MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/mysqli)); note the trailing **i**.

To sum up:

- Make sure you're able to see error messages (there's no need to guess).
- Browse for the correct package.