# mysqli extension is missing debian

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, debian

i m try to install mysql-sever on debian (WD mycloud live)

i have tried everything i found on google but no success

/etc/php5/conf.d/mysqli.ini  Dont exists

for install i used apt-get -f mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

so far i have

mysql running

```
 PHP Version 5.4.11-1
 Linux WDMyCloud 3.2.26 #1 SMP Fri Dec 27 13:50:41 PST 2013 armv7l

 Additional .ini files parsed   
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, 
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-apc.ini, 
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini, 
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, 
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/include_path.ini

 mysql -- version -> mysql ver 14.14 distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (armv71) using readline 6.2
```

i installed webmin there i can see my mysql-server information, i have there

```
Path to mysqlshow command    - /usr/bin/mysqlshow
Path to mysqladmin command   - /usr/bin/mysqladmin
Path to mysql command        - /usr/bin/mysql
Path to mysqldump command    - /usr/bin/mysqldump
Path to mysqlimport command  - /usr/bin/mysqlimport
MySQL configuration file     - /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Mysql Unix socket            - /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Database files directory     - /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Will install package containing both old one and the new one, so afterwards all you need to do is to add

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

in your php.ini, restart apache and it should work.

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835420/3566788

Comment: @okias if i try this dont works   
WDMyCloud:~# apt-get install php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 isc-dhcp-client : Depends: isc-dhcp-common (= 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u2) but 4.2.2
.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6 is to be installed
 php5-mysql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.4-14+deb7u8) but 5.4.11-1 is to be ins
talled
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a s
olution).

Comment: did you tried run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` before?

Comment: Hi @okias yes i tried everything i found on google like  first apt-get -f install  apt-get update && upgrade - the problem looks like be relationed to this  isc-dhcp-client i cant update this pack

Comment: Now throws: E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate

Comment: For PHP 8.1 use `sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered above issue while configuring 'phpmyadmin' for php5.7 and mysql@5 combination that was required for one of my old raspberry pi projects.

In my case when I tried the

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

I got error -

> E: Package 'php5-mysqli' has no installation candidate

The error also mentioned about the replacement packages,

> Package php5-mysqli is not available, but is referred to by another
> package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the
> following packages replace it:   **php5-mysqlnd** php5-mysql

I executed following and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt install php5-mysqlnd
```

Hope it helps.