# ajax call occuring internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internal-server-error

I am doing `ajax call`. And every time it is failing with occurring a `500 Internal server error`. But **no error in the client side code**.

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"html",
    data:{
        userInput:userInput /* userInput is some text value */
    }
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test");
    $user_data=$_POST['userInput'];
    echo $user_data;
?>
```

every time I see these error codes in console:

`POST XHR http://localhost/test.php` and `[HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]`

*Ask me if you need more informations*.

`NB`:I found many questions in this community. **None of those solved my problem**.

Comment: Where do you get the idea from that there's a 500 error? It quite clearly states _404 Not Found_, which would suggest the url (localhost/test.php) is incorrect. Also try adding a success and error callback to the `$.ajax` call, so you can log more info there

Comment: Are you sure that `test.php` is actually located at the root of server?

Comment: Are you sure both test.php and the file in which you use ajax are in same directory?

Comment: `test.php` and `test.html` are in same directory

Comment: Maybe do you have set some rule at the RewriteEngine?

Comment: Verify the method is POST our  is GET in php app.

Comment: I din't create htaccess file

Comment: @EmirMarques: It's post, that's clear when looking at the code. To the OP: what error are you actually getting? It was 404 originally, you've now changed it to 500. Which on is it? And again: add a success/error callback, and do a simple `console.log(arguments)` and look at what's being passed to those functions

Comment: I see now the error code is 500, so check out your `php_error_log` file for errors (or add a callback as @EliasVanOotegem proposed).

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, once I got 404 error, but currently I get 500 error

Comment: FWIW: Firebug tends to give you a lot more information on ajax errors than chrome or IE (if you aren't using it already)

Comment: `error:function(jqXHR){console.log(jqXHR);}` gives this error: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: SOLVED. It was a syntax error, But I was surprised that,  it was showing internal server error!!

Comment: @partho: A syntax error? Next time: please post the _actual_ code you're using, most of us would've been able to spot that quite quickly. And it's no surprise that a syntax error returns a 500 status: invalid syntax means php probably gave a fatal error, because it was unable to run the invalid code. That, in my book, is an internal server error

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, i am sorry. And thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the internal server error is due to the `mysqli_connect` function call with mysqli extension not enabled. Try `phpifo()` to verify mysqli extension is enabled

Comment: Client API library version  5.5.44
Active Persistent Links  0
Inactive Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0
Client API header version  5.5.44
MYSQLI_SOCKET  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Directive Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile On On
mysqli.allow_persistent On On
mysqli.default_host no value no value
mysqli.default_pw no value no value
mysqli.default_socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_user no value no value
mysqli.max_links Unlimited Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect Off Off

Comment: you suspected right. commenting out `mysqli_connect` i see no error. `mysqli` isn't enabled. I am trying to enable it. Help me please? Using `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

Comment: Find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

You can catch your error executing a callback .. example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"html",
    data:{
        userInput:userInput /* userInput is some text value */
    }
}).success(function() {
    window.alert('Ajax completed successfully');
}).error(function() {
    window.alert('An error has occurred');
});
```