# Problems getting php to connect to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I run a website on a LEMP stack, and up till today php queried a MySQL db no problems. Today, upon reboot it stopped, also phpmyadmin also stopped working. The php.ini file got updated recently (via aptitude) and the the only thing I have changed is the cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0 section. The versions are:

- php5 5.6.19-0+deb8u1
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47
- Debian Jessie
- phpmyadmin 4.2.12-2+deb

When I load phpmyadmin I get the following:

*"The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information."*

The documentation implies fiddling with extension=mysql.so which I have enabled and disabled to no avail. I have also attempted multiple service restarts of nginx, mysql and php5-fpm.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work) is not a duplicate as I have already attempted the restarting all services after uncommenting and recommenting extension=mysqli.so

Comment: @miken32 I have attempted that solution to no avail.

Comment: As it turns out re-installing php5-mysql seemed to work, although it threw out my phpmyadmin, which I will now try to fix.