# PHP/MySQL object-oriented mysqli will not connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a rather simple script here that I can't get to work:

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $user='root';
    $passwd='password';
    $db='cherry_pie';

    echo 'Accessing database...<br/>';
    $mysql_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $db);
    if($mysql_conn->connect_error) die($mysql_conn->connect_error);
?>
```

The result in my browser is simply:

> Accessing database...

Furthermore, no change in the web page occured after transposing

```
if($mysql_conn->connect_error) die($mysql_conn->connect_error);
```

with

```
print_r($mysql_conn);
```

which leaves me to believe that $mysql_conn is never being created.

---

I'm currently running ubuntu 16.04 and I've already run

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install mysql-client
```

Furthermore, I've run mysql through the shell and can verify that the database 'cherry_pie' does indeed exist.

Obviously my apache2 server is up and running and I already have other html documents and php scripts that will run properly.

I've already spent hours searching the php and mysql documentation, and I've referred to several other posts on this site to no avail, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

I've also tried using mysqli_connect() which did not work.

Here's what my error log has to say:

> [Fri Jun 23 13:10:38.214070 2017] [:error] [pid 12584] [client 127.0.0.1:56418] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/php_test.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/php_test.php on line 8, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error logs? You are missing a semicolon on this line `$mysql_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $db)`.

Comment: `$mysql_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $db)`, does this code contain semicolon at the end?

Comment: It does have a semi-colon, that was just a mis-copy.

Comment: [***Read And Then Respond To The Suggestions In Your PHP Error Log***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Try adding some curly brackets...`if ($mysqli->connect_error) {   
 die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error); }`

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms you have  indicates that your MySQLi library is not loaded by your current PHP build.

- [Read about how to use PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)
- [Read here about how to load the MySQLi library module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work).

> EDIT

While `MySQL` **IS** loaded, your `mysqli_` module is ***NOT*** loaded. So please see the link above.

Comment: You sir are my hero. I've been grappling with this since 7am this morning. I've now got MySQLi loaded and proper PHP error reporting. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AldenB glad to help, always check your error logs, they're very useful!

Comment: Honestly I didn't know that my PHP/MySQL errors would show up there; and yes, they are very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled $mysql_conn

```
    //Replace
        if($mysql_conn->connect_error) die(%mysql_conn->connect_error);
    //With
        if($mysql_conn->connect_error) die($mysql_conn->connect_error);

//He edited the post and corrected his spelling mistakes disregard this suggestion.
```

Comment: That was a mis-copy, my actual code has the '$'. I apologize for that.

Comment: Did you try 
echo (($mysql_conn->connect_error) ? "" : die($mysql_conn->connect_error));

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If you are creating a new `mysqli` connection object, you must have to follow its rules:

```
if($mysqli_conn->error) die($mysqli_conn->error);
```

Comment: The error log on the edited question clearly states that the `mysqli` class isn't there, so it's nothing to do with following the coding convention.

Comment: That's the bit to change. But reminding as he has it it's right. So i suggest you @AldenB to connect & verify using this way: `$mysql_conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $db) or die('Error connecting');` ... It it simple anyway it always return an only error message.