# "The mysqli extension is missing" - Getting this error when trying to access phpmyAdmin via localhost

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHP 5.6 and I got this error when trying to connect to phpmyadmin via localhost. I've already uncommented the extensions in php.ini and it still does not work. Any help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension mysqli is missing, phpmyadmin doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work)

Comment: If you could add more information about your environment including web server version I think you'll be more likely to receive assistance. Currently, your question is nearly un-answerable with the information provided.

Comment: Did you restart your web server after uncommenting the extension in your php.ini?

Comment: Yep, I've done it many times. Also im using windows 10, Web server version Apache2.4